# Is it possible to dispatch a successful DOS attack on a firewall with all ports closed?

Tags: networking, ddos, denial-of-service

I am wondering if my network is vulnerable to (D)DoS attacks even though I have no ports open. Currently, I am thinking that you should be able to throw random malformed packets at my public IP, forcing the firewall to sort through all of them. If I sent enough packets, would this be a decent way to take down a whole network?

Comment: Depending a bit on your upstream bandwidth for how many packets that should be, yes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a general networking question and not about programming.